# How to read a data frame PC serial over PIC UART

Tags: terminal, serial-port, pic, uart, mplab

I am trying to receive a frame having data from PC to PIC12F1572 over UART
My objective is to make a code to receive the data like RGBFF0000\n  which is the RGB LED configuration..Anyone has Idea about how to do it..I have done some code but I want to make it logically correct.
I use PIC12F1572 and MPLAB V3.50
Code ,correction and hints are highly appreciated 
Thanks in advance
Here is my code:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#define AT_COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE 256


uint8_t buffer[AT_COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t i = 0;
uint8_t receivedByte ;
/*
                         Main application
 */
/*-----------------R.E.C.E.I.V.E.R PIC------------*/
void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();


    EUSART_Write(0x61);
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();      // Enable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();     // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts

    // Disable the Global Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();

    // Disable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable();

    while (1)
    {
     if ( UART_DataReady() )            // If data is received,
        {
          receivedByte = EUSART_Read();
          for (i = 0; i<20 ; i++)
          {
            if ( receivedByte == '')
            {
                //My pb is how to start to check the data received over UART RX
            } 


          }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending new line character `\n` at the end of each command, So read `recievedByte` up to `\n` and store it in a new array. Then set a flag to show a valid command reception. After processing the new command clear this flag.

```
 if ( UART_DataReady() )            // If data is received,
    {
        receivedByte = EUSART_Read();
        for (i = 0; i<20 ; i++)
        {
            if ( receivedByte != '\n')
            {
                data[i] = receivedByte;

            }
            else{
                data[i] = '\0';
                data_flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well i tried this but I can not see the receiving data and now I am more looking for if I receive the data in the buffer data[] how can I use that to flash my leds..thanks if you have some solution on this :)

Comment: I checked and I found till receivedByte = EUSART_Read(); the code works and after that it is not getting enter in for loop so couldn't check the if ( receivedByte != '\n').....:(  I am using Hterm to send the data

Comment: Why don't you write this in ISR. I think it is the most efficient way. And you have to come out of the for loop after setting data_flag because data will be ready by that time

Comment: I made some changes in my answer, please check.

Comment: ..Okay I check it..actually I got the answer from it ..thanx by d way..I am looking for the conversion of input ascii to hex from the data i get from the UART,..If you may know the hint or solution I will be grateful to read that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "atoh.h"
#include "LED.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#define FRAMESIZE 20
void main(void)
{
   uint8_t data,i,j,got_char;


   uint8_t value;
   uint8_t RX_Buffer[FRAMESIZE];


    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();                       // Enable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();                   // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts

  while (1)
 {

        if (EUSART_DataReady)
        {
            for (i = 0; i<FRAMESIZE; i++)
            {
                RX_Buffer[i] = EUSART_Read();
                if (RX_Buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                  break;
                }
            }
            RX_Buffer[18] = '\n';
            RX_Buffer[i] = 0;
            EUSART_WriteAnArrayOfBytes(RX_Buffer);
        }
```